# NoClassDefFoundError when starting android project

Tags: android, eclipse, apk, adt, noclassdeffounderror

After updating my Android SDK today none of my projects are working anymore.
Whenever I try to run a project in the emulator I get a NoClassDefFoundError for the main class of the project.

This class usually comes from another library project, that is linked with my main project (via right-click -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Add...).

PS: all my JARs are in a "libs" folder, so that shouldn't be a problem...

Comment: First make sure that any JAR libraries are checked in `Properties -> Java Build Path -> Order and Export` (if they're there). Next make sure that `Properties -> Android` has the library (at the bottom). Lastly ensure that you have cleaned any libraries you have open in Eclipse, then clean the project you're compiling.

Comment: As I wrote below: my library project does not appear in the Android-add-dialog. The list is just empty.

Comment: [Try this once](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11824038/940096)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you try add them as referenced projects in the Android section of the project properties.

Comment: I tried that. But when trying to add something there, the list is just empty. Is there anything I have to do with my referenced library project, so that it appears in the android section?

Comment: It is opened in my workspace. So there must be some other problem?

Answer (score 2):

You can also get this error if you have installed different versions of the JRE on the same machine. If you installed a previous version of the JRE for another program, its quite possible that you installed a newer version when you installed JDK. Just uninstall the older version and you should be good to go.