# android 4.1 NoClassDefFoundError org.bouncycastle.asn1

Tags: android, noclassdeffounderror

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting NoClassDefFoundError when using common.lang.StringUtils in android java code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11823975/getting-noclassdeffounderror-when-using-common-lang-stringutils-in-android-java)

I'm new in android.

my application crashes on the device with ANdroid 4.1.

```
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.X509Name
at android.net.http.DomainNameChecker.matchDns(DomainNameChecker.java:187)
at android.net.http.DomainNameChecker.match(DomainNameChecker.java:62)
at com.android.email.mail.store.TrustManagerFactory$SecureX509TrustManager.checkServerTrusted(TrustManagerFactory.java:82)
at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.verifyCertificateChain(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:597)
at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:395)
at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl$SSLInputStream.<init>(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:647)
at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.getInputStream(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:618)
at com.android.email.mail.store.ImapStore$ImapConnection.open(ImapStore.java:1330)
```

On devices with andorid less than 4.1 everything is working well.
Who can tell me . where is problem?

list of included libraries

```
Yes. in bottom list of included libraries:
google-http-client-1.6.0-beta.jar
google-http-client-extensions-1.6.0-beta.jar
google-http-client-extensions-android2-1.6.0-beta.jar
```

Yahoo I did found right solution:

**In android 4.1 there is no bouncycastle library. I added it into project and the error disappeared**

Comment: Have you used any external `.jar` file?

Comment: Yes. I appended list of included libraries

Comment: [Try this once](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11823975/getting-noclassdeffounderror-when-using-common-lang-stringutils-in-android-java/11824038#11824038)

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

1. Remove all references to the JAR in your `project -> Java Build path --> Libraries.`
2. Create a `libs folder` at the root of your project
   Copy the JAR into the libs folder
3. If still not running OK. Right click your project > Android Tools > Fix Project Properties

Clean your project once and Run .

Comment: All my .jar files are already in libs/ folder. 
Do I need to recreate libs/ folder ?

Comment: no need to create new one. are you deleted all jar files from java Build Path..

Comment: No. Problem was in Android 4.1. On Android < 4.1 my library was included natively.

Comment: Just follow my steps it will solve your problem ...i was updated my answer look at that..