# Java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError - JavaMail

Tags: java, android

I have a thread inside my main activity, which will create an object of the class `SendMail`

```
package Logic;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.activation.DataHandler;
import javax.activation.FileDataSource;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Multipart;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.AddressException;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart;

import android.util.Log;

public class SendMail {

String from;
String to;
String subject;
String bodyText;
String fileName;

public SendMail(String to, String fileName, String PCN) {

    this.to = to;
    this.fileName = fileName;
    this.from = "Hello@gmail.com";
    this.bodyText = "FILE";
    this.subject = PCN;
}

public void sendMailWithAttatchment() {

    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("mail.smtp.host", "IP_ADDRESS");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "25");
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties, null);

    MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

    try {

        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

        message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(
                to));
        message.setSubject(subject);
        message.setSentDate(new Date());

        MimeBodyPart messagePart = new MimeBodyPart();
        messagePart.setText(bodyText);

        MimeBodyPart attachmentPart = new MimeBodyPart();

        FileDataSource fileDataSource = new FileDataSource(fileName) {
            @Override
            public String getContentType() {
                return "application/octet-stream";

            }
        };

        attachmentPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(fileDataSource));
        attachmentPart.setFileName(fileDataSource.getName());

        Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
        multipart.addBodyPart(messagePart);
        multipart.addBodyPart(attachmentPart);
        message.setContent(multipart);
        Transport.send(message);
    } catch (AddressException e) {
        Log.e("ADDRESS_EXCEPTION: ", e.getMessage());
    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        Log.e("MESSAGING_EXCEPTION: ", e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

}

But the compiler throws an Exception saying: `Java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError. javax.activation.Datahandler`

I've read this thread: [NoClassDefFoundError - Eclipse and Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2247998/noclassdeffounderror-eclipse-and-android) and the `.jar files` `javamail.jar` and `javax.activation.jar` is located under my `libs` folder, but this throws an exception even if I clean the project.

Any ideas?

These are the exception which is thrown:

```
08-07 10:19:49.870: E/AndroidRuntime(17736): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.activation.DataHandler
08-07 10:19:49.870: E/AndroidRuntime(17736):    at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.setContent(MimeBodyPart.java:647)
08-07 10:19:49.870: E/AndroidRuntime(17736):    at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.setText(MimeBodyPart.java:892)
08-07 10:19:49.870: E/AndroidRuntime(17736):    at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.setText(MimeBodyPart.java:680)
08-07 10:19:49.870: E/AndroidRuntime(17736):    at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.setText(MimeBodyPart.java:668)
08-07 10:19:49.870: E/AndroidRuntime(17736):    at sendMailWithAttatchment(SendMail.java:56)
08-07 10:19:49.870: E/AndroidRuntime(17736):    at sendMailWithAttatchment(SendMail.java:56)
08-07 10:19:49.870: E/AndroidRuntime(17736):    at CreateNistFile(MyActivity.java:530)
```

Answer (score 5):

java introduce new way for javaMail for android :

you need just add thi lines in gradle:

```
 android {
     packagingOptions {
         pickFirst 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt' // picks the JavaMail license file
     }
 }

 repositories { 
     jcenter()
     maven {
         url "https://maven.java.net/content/groups/public/"
     }
 }

 dependencies {
     compile 'com.sun.mail:android-mail:1.5.5'
     compile 'com.sun.mail:android-activation:1.5.5'
 }
```

and do the smtp mail like you did... 
good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this because of your .jar file didn't import properly. Just follow my existing [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11824038/940096) It will helps you surely. And, below snapshot is important (It notifies the additional jar files should looks like this image) -

[image]

Important thing is, whenever you'd `Java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` exception above one is the solution to handle that.

Comment: Thanks for your answe, but this doesnt work for me. Before the exception is thrown, I got this debug information: Failed resolving Ljavax/activation/DataHandler; interface 272 'Ljava/awt/datatransfer/Transferable;'

Comment: Are you trying for [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-built-in-a)

Comment: No, I am following this tutorial: [link](http://www.kodejava.org/examples/243.html) I doesnt want to have any user interactions nor any popups of installed email clients on the phone. The mail should contain subject, bodytext and an attacment.

Comment: Fine. Now, can you please post your full `LogCat` trace after getting exception?

Comment: @TobiasMoeThorstensen Yes it seems, `.jar` file didn't imported properly. Did you try my existing answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using eclipse, right click on project > choose properties> Java build Path> libraries> add Jars and add the jars. Then clean the project

Comment: I've done that, as a matter of fact this is not what I am asking for. Your answer is too obvious.

Comment: @TobiasMoeThorstensen That Solves my problem most of the time, so was just trying to help. No issues.

Answer (score 0):

Android isn't fully Java-compliant, there's the javamail-android project that adds support for Javamail to Android apps.

make sure you download and add to build path **all 3 jars** from here: http://code.google.com/p/javamail-android/downloads/list