# Is it possible to create a one way "request form" in my app?

Tags: java, android

Ive created the UI design for a "request form" in which the user enters their request for a specific song. Id like the user's request to be sent to my email, but the user wouldn't have to use their own email, theyd just have to enter the details and click the button whcih would then sen m the request. Is this possible? If it is how can i apply this. if not then is there another way? Thank You

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25136025/sending-mail-in-android-without-intents-using-smtp

Comment: yes its possible. best way is to create an app with a backend (firebase) and just save the information from the form submission to firebase. then you, since your the admin, will get a notification, click it, you are deeplinked ino your app with a list of messages.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot send message without mail address, but you can create a mail by yourself, hardcode it into your app, and use as sender address. Also you can pass all data about user that you need (if you collect it), if you want to recognize one, in the message