# How to attach file from gallery in smpt mail?

Tags: android

Code to upload the image.

```
private EditText editTextEmail;
private EditText editTextSubject;
private EditText editTextMessage;

//Send button
private Button buttonSend;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Initializing the views

    editTextMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextMessage);

    buttonSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSend);

    //Adding click listener
    buttonSend.setOnClickListener(this);
}


private void sendEmail() {
    //Getting content for email
    String email = "xxxxxxx";
    String subject = "xxxxx";
    String message = editTextMessage.getText().toString().trim();

    //Creating SendMail object
    SendMail sm = new SendMail(this, email, subject, message);

    //Executing sendmail to send email
    sm.execute();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    sendEmail();
}
}
```

Deliver the mail with attached file

only mail is delivered

Comment: have a look at [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25136400/4168607).

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
    emailIntent.setType("application/image");
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{strEmail}); 
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"Subject"); 
    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "From..."); 
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file:///mnt/sdcard/image.jpeg"));
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
```