# Send an e-mail using Javamail

Tags: android, email, smtp, jakarta-mail

I am trying to send an e-mail using the Javamail, since it seems to be the only way to send an e-mail using SMTP.

I searched some posts like:
[Sending mail in android without intents using SMTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25136025/sending-mail-in-android-without-intents-using-smtp])

But, I want a sender to be my own domain, not the gmail.

So I tried:

```
    final String username = "admin@customsite.com";
    final String password = "password";

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.customsite.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

    Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
            new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
                }
            });
        try {
            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("admin@customsite.com"));
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                    InternetAddress.parse("username@gmail.com"));
            message.setSubject("Hello there");
            message.setText("This is a test email");
            Transport.send(message);
            Log.d("EmailClient", "Success");
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
```

But it seems not to be working.

Comment: Would sending the email from a server in the cloud be an option/of interest to you?  The way I have done it is to just use a Java web application which can be reached via a REST call from the Android app.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Well, I thought sending an e-mail using Javamail was simple, I must look at how to send mail using REST?

Comment: No, what I was suggesting is that if you write a server side program/script, you can send mail by any method you want.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen If you mean using a PHP or something like that, I am afraid I am extremely weak about passing an email address to server and sending an email using that data.

Comment: @mium so have you installed a smtp in your server?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yes

Comment: @Mium what does "not working" mean?  What debugging have you done?  How does it fail?  What does the [JavaMail debug output](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#debug) show?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've done the same a week ago, with a custom smtp here's my code

Class SendMail.JAVA , I have Password and Mail Account in Config.JAVA, Take note that my server was running on port 25 and didn't have SSL

```
public class SendMail extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {

//Declaring Variables
private Context context;
private Session session;

//Information to send email
private String email;
private String subject;
private String message;

//Progressdialog to show while sending email
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

//Class Constructor
public SendMail(Context context, String email, String subject, String message){
    //Initializing variables
    this.context = context;
    this.email = email;
    this.subject = subject;
    this.message = message;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    //Showing progress dialog while sending email
    progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(context,"Enviando mail","Espere por favor...",false,false);
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
    super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    //Dismissing the progress dialog
    progressDialog.dismiss();
    //Showing a success message
    Toast.makeText(context,"Mail enviado",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    //Creating properties
    Properties props = new Properties();

    //Configuring properties for gmail
    //If you are not using gmail you may need to change the values
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "Custom SMTP");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "25");

    //Creating a new session
    session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
            new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                //Authenticating the password
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {

                    return new PasswordAuthentication(Config.EMAIL, Config.PASSWORD);
                }
            });

    try {
        //Creating MimeMessage object
        MimeMessage mm = new MimeMessage(session);

        //Setting sender address
        mm.setFrom(new InternetAddress(Config.EMAIL));
        //Adding receiver
        mm.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(email));
        //Adding subject
        mm.setSubject(subject);
        //Adding message
        mm.setText(message, "utf-8", "html");

        //Sending email
        Transport.send(mm);

    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

}

Example implementation in Activity

```
private void sendEmail() {
        //Getting content for email
        String email = asd.getText().toString();
        String subject = "Presupuesto plaza hogar";
        String message = body.toString();

        //Creating SendMail object
        SendMail sm = new SendMail(this, email, subject, message);

        //Executing sendmail to send email
        sm.execute();
    }
```

Comment: If SendMail handles ProgressDialog, how can I handle the next process in activity? I think I have to get return value, but I get no idea

Comment: @Mium Explain more please, I really don't know what you're triying to do :P

Comment: I mean I implied sm.execute in activity, how can this activity knows the email sending is complete? (I think I have to get return value like true and false)

Comment: @mium in sendmail.java handle the exception in the try catch, just do this
 } catch (MessagingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
Your Toast Message HERE


    }


 if the mail still not beign delivered and you have no error in your code then you have a problem on your server side

Comment: I mean I want to use ProgressBar (since Progressdialog is deprecated) so I designed ProgressBar in my activity. If the Mail process is complete, I want to disable ProgressBar like: progressbar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); To do that, I have to identify if the process is completed or sending in progress.

Comment: @mium ahh not i got you :P, yea, just make a boolean in sendmail.java and set it to true only if it completes the process, and set it to false in the exception, then just read the value from your activity

Comment: Thanks a lot. It reallty did help me to boost progress