# Exception when using jtransform in android - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: edu.emory.mathcs.jtransforms.fft.DoubleFFt_1D

Tags: android, fft, frequency

When I am using jTransform.

https://sites.google.com/site/piotrwendykier/software/jtransforms

with my app to perform FFT to my pcm data, I got the exception

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: edu.emory.mathcs.jtransforms.fft.DoubleFFt_1D`

while I added the `jtransform.jar` in my app.And also update the build path.

Comment: [Have you tried this one?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11824038/940096)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.In Project properties -> Java build path -> Order and export, check all your added dependencies to be included with project class files.

2.Select Android Tools > Fix Project Properties

Than run your app. Its work perfectly.

Comment: What IDE were you using?  Any updates for Android Studio?