# Android: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, android, math, gradle

I am attempting to use the JTransforms library to compute a math function (DoubleFFT_1D) in an Android app (using the latest Android Studio).  I am using the .jar file provided from the JTransforms [website](https://github.com/wendykierp/JTransforms) and have imported it to the project.  I have tried both JTransforms Revision 2.4 and 3.1.  The code compiles with no errors, but when I get to the actual method call, I get the following error message:

```
09-07 17:30:11.369 E/JavaBinder: *** Uncaught remote exception!  (Exceptions are not yet supported across processes.)
                                 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/jtransforms/fft/DoubleFFT_1D;
                                     at com.algoint.libzante.AutoCorrelation.compute(AutoCorrelation.java:66)
                                     at com.algoint.libzante.EstimateACF.estimateInSamplePeriods(EstimateACF.java:104)
                                     at <snip>
com.algoint.zante.BluetoothLeService.broadcastUpdate(BluetoothLeService.java:348)
                                     at com.algoint.zante.BluetoothLeService.access$700(BluetoothLeService.java:50)
                                     at com.algoint.zante.BluetoothLeService$1.onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothLeService.java:243)
                                     at android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt$1.onNotify(BluetoothGatt.java:438)
                                     at android.bluetooth.IBluetoothGattCallback$Stub.onTransact(IBluetoothGattCallback.java:399)
                                     at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:453)
                                  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.jtransforms.fft.DoubleFFT_1D" on path: DexPathList[[dex file "/data/data/com.algoint.zante/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_9-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.algoint.zante/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_8-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.algoint.zante/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_7-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.algoint.zante/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_6-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.algoint.zante/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_5-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.algoint.zante/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_4-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.algoint.zante/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_3-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.algoint.zante/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_2-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.algoint.zante/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_1-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.algoint.zante/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_0-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.algoint.zante/files/instant-run/dex/slice-json_simple-1.1_9ec115b071c72fb6edf2028f7a57e4ae60bb5a65-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.algoint.zante/files/instant-run/dex/slice-dropbox-android-sdk-1.5.4_74a0c4010a6328c8c6443241412fa9c5c398a9ab-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.algoint.zante/files/instant-run/dex/slice-achartengine-1.1.0_0238cc7eb0f70b6065b267fb6df8a8f6b48a5319-classes.dex"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.algoint.zante-2/lib/arm64, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
                                     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                                     at com.android.tools.fd.runtime.IncrementalClassLoader$DelegateClassLoader.findClass(IncrementalClassLoader.java:90)
                                     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
                                     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
                                     at com.algoint.libzante.AutoCorrelation.compute(AutoCorrelation.java:66) 
                                     at com.algoint.libzante.EstimateACF.estimateInSamplePeriods(EstimateACF.java:104) 
                                     at <snip>
com.algoint.zante.BluetoothLeService.broadcastUpdate(BluetoothLeService.java:348) 
                                     at com.algoint.zante.BluetoothLeService.access$700(BluetoothLeService.java:50) 
                                     at com.algoint.zante.BluetoothLeService$1.onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothLeService.java:243) 
                                     at android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt$1.onNotify(BluetoothGatt.java:438) 
                                     at android.bluetooth.IBluetoothGattCallback$Stub.onTransact(IBluetoothGattCallback.java:399) 
                                     at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:453) 
                                    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.jtransforms.fft.DoubleFFT_1D" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.algoint.zante-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.algoint.zante-2/lib/arm64, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
                                     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                                     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
                                     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
                                            ... 12 more
                                        Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.jtransforms.fft.DoubleFFT_1D" on path: DexPathList[[dex file "/data/data/com.algoint.zante/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_9-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.algoint.zante/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_8-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.algoint.zante/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_7-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.algoint.zante/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_6-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.algoint.zante/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_5-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.algoint.zante/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_4-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.
```

I have imported jtransforms as follows in the source file:

```
import org.jtransforms.fft.DoubleFFT_1D;
```

with the proper gradle entry:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile files('libs/JTransforms-3.1-with-dependencies.jar')
}
```

And corresponding Android Studio dependency setting:
[image]

The project compiles without an error and throws and error at the following line:

```
int n = 2 * nextPow2(x.length);
// Twice the number of elements are required: real and imaginary parts of the FFT are stored consecutively
double[] f = new double[2 * n];   
System.arraycopy(x, 0, f, 0, x.length);
// FFT
DoubleFFT_1D fft = new DoubleFFT_1D((long) n);  // ERROR ON THIS LINE
// Use "full" to avoid more machinations with symmetry
fft.realForwardFull(f);
```

The value of n when the error is thrown is 1024 and the length of x is 500.
I have found this error with both: "JTransforms-2.4.jar" and "JTransforms-3.1-with-dependencies.jar".  I think the original project was compiled in Maven, does that make a difference?
Can you recommend any solutions?
Thank you.

Comment: Just fixed a formatting problem with a code block.

Comment: Does the "fix project properties" thing from the answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11845451/exception-when-using-jtransform-in-android-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-edu fix your problem?

Comment: It didnt help.  Mostly because the instructions are for eclipse, and I am using Android Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately, I found a solution.  I ignored the .jar file and just compiled the source straight into the project.  Procedure:
- pulled the full git repository for Jtransforms, 
- converted it from a Maven project to a Gradle project ("gradle init"), 
- imported it as a module into my project and then 
- compiled it in.
I did have some trouble with removing all the original .jar files (buried in the directories), but once I had done that the project compiled and ran fine.