# How to fix NoClassDefFoundError occured while using a third party library in our application?

Tags: android, android-library, android-datepicker

I am using [**android wheel**](http://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/) to select date and time in my application. but i am fed up with this `NoClassDefFoundError` while using this library.

I included `wheel.jar` in the `libs` folder, but still i get error at runtime.

Here is the `logcat` error:

> 08-08 15:19:22.078: E/AndroidRuntime(21223): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       08-08 15:19:22.078: E/AndroidRuntime(21223): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kankan.wheel.R$drawable
>       08-08 15:19:22.078: E/AndroidRuntime(21223):    at kankan.wheel.widget.WheelView.initResourcesIfNecessary(WheelView.java:427)
>       08-08 15:19:22.078: E/AndroidRuntime(21223):    at kankan.wheel.widget.WheelView.calculateLayoutWidth(WheelView.java:482)
>       08-08 15:19:22.078: E/AndroidRuntime(21223):    at kankan.wheel.widget.WheelView.onMeasure(WheelView.java:518)
>       08-08 15:19:22.078: E/AndroidRuntime(21223):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12775)
>       08-08 15:19:22.078: E/AndroidRuntime(21223):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
>       08-08 15:19:22.078: E/AndroidRuntime(21223):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1385)
>       08-08 15:19:22.078: E/AndroidRuntime(21223):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1027)
>       08-08 15:19:22.078: E/AndroidRuntime(21223):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:565)
>       08-08 15:19:22.078: E/AndroidRuntime(21223):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12775)
>       08-08 15:19:22.078: E/AndroidRuntime(21223):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:594)
>       08-08 15:19:22.078: E/AndroidRuntime(21223):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:376)
>       08-08 15:19:22.078: E/AndroidRuntime(21223):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12775)
>       08-08 15:19:22.078: E/AndroidRuntime(21223):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:594)
>       08-08 15:19:22.078: E/AndroidRuntime(21223):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:376)
>       08-08 15:19:22.078: E/AndroidRuntime(21223):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12775)
>       08-08 15:19:22.078: E/AndroidRuntime(21223):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
>       08-08 15:19:22.078: E/AndroidRuntime(21223):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
>       08-08 15:19:22.078: E/AndroidRuntime(21223):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12775)
>       08-08 15:19:22.078: E/AndroidRuntime(21223):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
>       08-08 15:19:22.078: E/AndroidRuntime(21223):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
>       08-08 15:19:22.078: E/AndroidRuntime(21223):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12775)
>       08-08 15:19:22.078: E/AndroidRuntime(21223):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
>       08-08 15:19:22.078: E/AndroidRuntime(21223):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
>       08-08 15:19:22.078: E/AndroidRuntime(21223):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2240)
>       08-08 15:19:22.078: E/AndroidRuntime(21223):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12775)
>       08-08 15:19:22.078: E/AndroidRuntime(21223):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1151)
>       08-08 15:19:22.078: E/AndroidRuntime(21223):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2539)
>       08-08 15:19:22.078: E/AndroidRuntime(21223):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>       08-08 15:19:22.078: E/AndroidRuntime(21223):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>       08-08 15:19:22.078: E/AndroidRuntime(21223):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4514)
>       08-08 15:19:22.078: E/AndroidRuntime(21223):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>       08-08 15:19:22.078: E/AndroidRuntime(21223):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>       08-08 15:19:22.078: E/AndroidRuntime(21223):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
>       08-08 15:19:22.078: E/AndroidRuntime(21223):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
>       08-08 15:19:22.078: E/AndroidRuntime(21223):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>       08-08 15:24:27.601: I/Process(21223): Sending signal. PID: 21223 SIG: 9

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10046725/1289716

Comment: `libs -> wheel.jar -> Right Click -> Build Path -> Add to Build Path `.

Comment: i think ..you are missing xml for wheel.. that xml you have to put in drawable..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Atlast i found the solution,

Instead of adding the jar file in the build path, go to project properties -> Android -> click add in the library section -> and select the library project.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You should try this:

1. `Remove` all references to the `JAR` in your project from `Java Build Path`.-> your code should not build without error anymore
2. Create a `libs folder` if not exist at the root of your project `Copy the JAR into the libs folder`.
3. If still not running OK. Right click your project > Android Tools > Fix Project Properties

`clean your project` and run. it will work

look at this existing answ [Getting NoClassDefFoundError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11823975/getting-noclassdeffounderror-when-using-common-lang-stringutils-in-android-java/11824038#11824038)

Comment: your answer helped me, but it wasn't the exact one. i have found the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Try Ordering and exporting your jar libraries within the project.

Follow the steps below(in Eclipse):

> 1. Go to project properties
> 2. Select Java Build Path
> 3. Select last tab "Order and Export"
> 4. Move Your Jar(Library) to the top position
> 5. Clean And Build Project

I don't know what is exactly happening, but once i had the same issue and I solved it in the above manner. Hope this will be a help to you too.