# Loading classes from jar on android

Tags: android, jar

I tried really hard, but always get a Class Not Found exception, from reading this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3024261

I took my jar run the

dx --dex --output=C:\classes.dex C:\MyAndroidLib.jar

and got a dex file

then I run the

apt add C:\MyLib.jar C:\classes.dex

to create a jar with the dex file.

then I wrote the following code.

```
DexClassLoader classLoader = new DexClassLoader(
            destPath, dirPath +"/" , null, getClass().getClassLoader());
    Class<?> classToLoad = classLoader.loadClass("ClassImpl");
```

on debug I can see that the dex is inside the classLoader(under the mDexs member)
and the ClassImpl is the only class I got inside.

but I keep getting the class not found exception.

Anyone got a working sample of dynamic class loading from external jar ?
Someone knows whats my problem?

Comment: You got `ClassNotFound Exception?` I'm not sure. Just try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11824005/940096) If you imported any `.jar` files into your project.

Comment: So sorry, suddenly it works....

Comment: How it works? Did you clean your project or tried that answer or what?

Comment: @ChenKinnrot How it starts working... i am having the same problem please help

Answer (score 1):

I did not use aapt... Only dex. And I got my class loaded, and my methods called.

Use this code for see inside the dex file:

```
DexFile dexfile = DexFile.loadDex(url_jar_path, 
        File.createTempFile("opt", "dex", context.getCacheDir()).getPath(), 0);

// Print all classes in the DexFile

Enumeration<String> classNames = dexfile.entries();

String classname = "";

while (true) {
    if (! classNames.hasMoreElements()) {
        break;
    }
    classname = classNames.nextElement();
}
```

Use this code for see inside the class:

```
Class class = dexclassloader.loadClass(ruta_clase_en_jar);

String name;

Method[] method_array = clase.getMethods();

for (Method i: method_array) {
    name = i.getName ();
}
```