# Cannot figure out the IMAP mailServer for gmail

Tags: android, jakarta-mail, mail-server

I'm making an application on android that retrieves emails from gmail accounts using JavaMail API.
Here's my code:

```
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
    props.setProperty("mail.imaps.host", mailServer);
    props.setProperty("mail.imaps.port", "993");
    props.setProperty("mail.imaps.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    props.setProperty("mail.imaps.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
    if (debug) Log.i("check","before session");
    Session imapSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,null);
    if (debug) Log.i("check","after session");
```

Whenever the code reaches the imapSession line, the application just crashes. In other words, it never reaches the last line.
I've tried several mailServer strings:

```
imaps.gmail.com
imap.gmail.com
imaps.googlemail.com
imap.googlemail.com
```

and nothing seems to work. Is it the port?
I'm sure I've added the right permissions, the error in the log cat doesn't mention the permissions anyways.

**Another question** where can I get such information for Gmail and other email servers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start by simplifying things.  You've made several of the [common JavaMail mistakes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes).  Throw your code away and use the [simple code in the JavaMail FAQ for connecting to Gmail](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#gmail).  Then use the [tips in the JavaMail FAQ for debugging](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) any remaining problems.  If you still have problems, post additional details here.

Comment: Thank you... I'll go through the links and come back to you. Sorry i got busy these days

Comment: So my mistakes were:
1-  Session imapSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,null);
2-  props.setProperty("mail.imaps.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");

what i did:
1- may make a problem for me latter, but for now i don't think it's the problem since the app crashes from the very first use. But anyways, its better to use .getInstance()... am I righ?
2- i removed it and set "mail.smtp.ssl.enable" to "true" as the link suggests. I also removed: props.setProperty("mail.imaps.socketFactory.fallback", "false");

Comment: there's still an error - here's the log - E/AndroidRuntime(19029): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.mail.Session           . . . i found that i have to add some jar files, but i did add them! where did i go wrong?!

Comment: Well, clearly you didn't add them correctly.  Is this what you meant by "the app is crashing" in your original post?  Anyway, it looks like you're into an Android-specific problem that someone else will have to help you with.  There's lots of other questions here about using JavaMail with Android so maybe a little searching will turn up the answer.

Comment: I have just fixed it. it seems that i had to arrange them in a certain order! i followed [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11823975/getting-noclassdeffounderror-when-using-common-lang-stringutils-in-android-java/11824038#11824038) it worked, but I don't understand why!!? do you have any idea?