# Adwhril sample example giving classnotfound exception

Tags: android, adwhirl

[image]i am having my manifest file like this

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.basic.adwhrilsample"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
   <activity android:name=".Invoker" android:label="@string/app_name">

  <intent-filter>

    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

  </intent-filter>

  <meta-data android:value="my sdk key"

    android:name="ADWHIRL_KEY"/>

</activity>
</application>
```

and the below is my main.xml file

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:id="@+id/layout_main">

<com.adwhirl.AdWhirlLayout
    android:id="@+id/adwhirl_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and my Invoker.java activity

```
package com.basic.adwhrilsample;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.adwhirl.AdWhirlLayout;
import com.adwhirl.AdWhirlLayout.AdWhirlInterface;
import com.adwhirl.AdWhirlManager;
import com.adwhirl.AdWhirlTargeting;

public class Invoker extends Activity implements AdWhirlInterface {

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    AdWhirlManager.setConfigExpireTimeout(1000 * 60 * 5);

    AdWhirlTargeting.setAge(23);

    AdWhirlTargeting.setGender(AdWhirlTargeting.Gender.MALE);

    AdWhirlTargeting.setKeywords("online games gaming");

    AdWhirlTargeting.setPostalCode("94123");

    AdWhirlTargeting.setTestMode(false);

    AdWhirlLayout adWhirlLayout = (AdWhirlLayout)    
findViewById(R.id.adwhirl_layout);

    TextView textView = new TextView(this);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,

    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    int diWidth = 320;

    int diHeight = 52;

    int density = (int) getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

    adWhirlLayout.setAdWhirlInterface(this);

    adWhirlLayout.setMaxWidth((int) (diWidth * density));

    adWhirlLayout.setMaxHeight((int) (diHeight * density));

    layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

    textView.setText("Below AdWhirlLayout");

    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_main);

    layout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

    layout.addView(adWhirlLayout, layoutParams);

    layout.addView(textView, layoutParams);

    layout.invalidate();

}

@Override
public void adWhirlGeneric() {

}

}
```

but i am getting

```
08-30 10:17:25.194: E/AndroidRuntime(564): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to     
instantiate activity   
ComponentInfo{com.basic.adwhrilsample/com.basic.adwhrilsample.Invoker}:  
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.basic.adwhrilsample.Invoker in loader  
dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.basic.adwhrilsample-2.apk]
```

Can anyone help me out in solving my issue.
Or can anyone provide me a sample working example so that i could follow it

Updated logcat  :

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to clean your project and restart your workspace to run the app again.

Comment: Then, simply try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11824038/940096)

Comment: @SharathG Have you defined AdWhirlLayout in *declare-styleable* tag of resource file yet?

Comment: [2012-08-30 11:02:18 - AdwhrilSample] Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1 . I am getting this error in console when i am trying to run it.
Please suggest me.

Comment: @R4j i just did the above xml layout in the resources and nothing else.
Am i missing anything?

Comment: @SpK I am still left with the same classnot found exception. Can you help me further please

Comment: Have you imported your `.jar` files into `libs` folder only?

Comment: yes i did it the same. uploaded my package explorer

Comment: Okay try to create a new project. And, copy those code from these projects. And, try to run.

Comment: Otherwise, have a look at [here](http://www.andengine.org/forums/tutorials/conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-with-error-1-t8178.html#p36032) also.

Comment: The link didnt solve my issue, but anyhow thanks for the link

Comment: Now have a look at the warnings please.I hope i will be suggested

Comment: the issue seems to be in your adapter.

Comment: Can i be suggested in any way?

Comment: found a way to solve my problem on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12200424/adwhril-sample-not-working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think everything is allright just replace imported package replace this

```
 import android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams;
```

by

```
 import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
```

Comment: [2012-08-30 11:02:18 - AdwhrilSample] Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1 . I am getting this error in console when i am trying to run it. Please suggest me.

Comment: clean and build your project i have the same code which works fine just change the line as given in answer also see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680827/conversion-to-dalvik-format-failed-with-error-1-on-external-jar it bcz of build path of library check it as shown at the above link

Comment: Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1 has been solved but i am with the same logcat error as in the question
can u suggest me please

Comment: Can i have a sample of the working ones so that i can download it and make it work please

Comment: @SharathG http://paste2.org/p/2168910 check this same code as you have pasted a single line of change check it

Comment: updated the warnings in the quesiton and even this error   java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

Comment: Initially i am getting some data but later i am not able to get the pictures onto my emulator nor even on the mobile. Can you suggest please

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting ur bin directory of the project and then clean the project build it and run. I think ur class file is not present in the  .dex extension it sometimes happens when the files dont get properly compiled. Also check if there is no error of build path.

Comment: can u share the full logcat output please ?

Comment: yes the above two captures are the full logcat output and next the same is beign repeated

Comment: I just wanted to make sure that the jar u included is getting packaged with ur class file. If not it can also cause the same error.

Comment: yes i included this jar file AdWhirlSDK_Android_3.1.1.jar .
Is this sufficient?

Comment: Which version of adt pluggin r u using ?

Comment: Comment all ur code which is using the reference to the jar u have included and then run the sample if it runs then ur jar file is not getting packaged with ur apk.

Comment: It is Android Development Toolkit

Version: 20.0.0.v201206242043-391819

Comment: please do what i mentioned in my last comment.

Comment: Now i am simply left with a blank screen with the same warnings as in the previous capture

Comment: i even got this above the warnings : java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first. I simply used this paste2.org/p/2168910  as my reference and changed the sdk key in it

Comment: check the same question here please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12200424/adwhril-sample-not-working