# Android custom ListAdapter - stopwatch

Tags: android

I doing simple stopwatch.

I have StopwatchActivity.java

I have ListAdapter but i need set custom font.

How to do it? I was looking for examples, but I can not find  the with  "String"

It works.

Code: 
http://pastebin.com/zgA0f0jq

To moderators: I have error when I need paste code here "Your post does not have much context to explain the code sections; please explain your scenario more clearly."

Comment: so what is wrong with your code?

Comment: If i add my custom ListAdapter i have error cause my new ListAdapter is wrong i have error in line with  m_lapList.clear();

Comment: check @SharathG answer. You will need to use a different kind of adapter to set custom font. You will need a handle of the TextView to set its font

Comment: chceck my comment to SharathG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this sample [here](http://codinglookseasy.blogspot.in/2012/08/localization-using-ttf-files.html)

you need to inflate it so that you can set the text with the font you need to have.
I can suggest you to use a baseadapter so that you can get the textview and set the typeface to it

Comment: It's my BaseAdapter. http://pastebin.com/Qvzq3tu3 i Have error in line m_lapList.clear();

Comment: The method clear() is undefined for the type StopwatchActivity.MyAdapter

Comment: public void onResetClicked(View v) {
     Log.d(TAG, "reset button clicked");
     m_stopwatchService.reset();
     
     m_lapList.clear();
    }

If i have normal ListAdapter it work.

Comment: you have used setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.laps_row)); in your code and its saying The method clear() is undefined for the type StopwatchActivity.MyAdapter ??

Comment: I using it like this:         setListAdapter(new MyAdapter(this, new ArrayList<Object>()));
        m_lapList = (MyAdapter)getListAdapter();

Comment: well try creating an object myadapter = new MyAdapter(this, new ArrayList<Object>() and call myadapter.clear();

Comment: I have it: setListAdapter(new MyAdapter(this, new ArrayList<Object>()));

Comment: instead am asking you to once check well try creating an object myadapter = new MyAdapter(this, new ArrayList<Object>() and call myadapter.clear();

Comment: It doesn't work. I think that problem is here : private MyAdapter m_lapList; before it was private ArrayAdapter<String> m_lapList;

Comment: Why did you use ArrayList<Object>() ? Is that a seperate class? or you are trying to use the Object of java.lang?

Comment: No I do not use. How else to write?

Comment: then what is Object? over there?

Comment: For constructor:   public MyAdapter (Context context, List<Object> objects) {
      this.context = context;
      this.objects = objects;
  }

Comment: What does that List<Objects> contain ?

Comment: Gets Item (int position)

BaseAdapter took from the example.

Comment: Well i suggest you to change Objects to String itself. It should solve your problem

Comment: It doesn't work. of course <String> works but error remained.

Comment: The method clear() is undefined for the type StopwatchActivity.MyAdapter

Comment: not just that some thing like this the screen capture at the end of the question in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12190242/adwhril-sample-example-giving-classnotfound-exception

Comment: I created methods for. Clear () and insert () and there is no error
But the program breaks where I shall write.

Comment: where did you write them? I am not able to find the clear and insert methods in the links

Comment: I wrote just now

  public void insert(String formattedElapsedTime, int i) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   m_lapList.insert(m_stopwatchService.getFormattedElapsedTime(), 0);
  }


  public void clear() {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   m_lapList.clear();
  }

Comment: then just call m_laplist.clear(); No need to write a method for that. 
hey what object is m_laplist ?

Comment: But when I called m_laplist.clear() i have error that undefined method. mlapList is private MyAdapter m_lapList; It's for new lap.

Comment: there is something that i am missing.....
well is it a private app that should not be revealed ?
If its not so try to post the entire code. I will try to check the problem with it

Comment: sharathg.satya@yahoo.co.in   I would do it the next day as it is midnight here and even i am not sure that i will come with a solution as it has something different classes and so which i need to refer . So please Dont mind and give the sample if you can

Answer (score 0):

You can set font to each TextView in your xml, like so:

```
<TextView 
android:id="@+id/button2"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:typeface="sans" />
```

Comment: No. I need change font for example DS-DIGIT.tff not sans/sheriff/italic etc.