# Unable to resolve superclass of Activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I am getting this error on a new project based on OpenGL ES 10:

```
  09-03 12:44:07.870: W/dalvikvm(599): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/example/basicgl10test/MainActivity; (416)
  09-03 12:44:07.870: W/dalvikvm(599): Link of class 'Lcom/example/basicgl10test/MainActivity;' failed
  09-03 12:44:07.870: D/AndroidRuntime(599): Shutting down VM
  09-03 12:44:07.910: W/dalvikvm(599): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
  09-03 12:44:07.920: I/dalvikvm(599): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
  09-03 12:44:07.980: E/AndroidRuntime(599): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  09-03 12:44:07.980: E/AndroidRuntime(599): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.basicgl10test/com.example.basicgl10test.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.basicgl10test.MainActivity
  09-03 12:44:07.980: E/AndroidRuntime(599):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1880)
  09-03 12:44:07.980: E/AndroidRuntime(599):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
  09-03 12:44:07.980: E/AndroidRuntime(599):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
  09-03 12:44:07.980: E/AndroidRuntime(599):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
  09-03 12:44:07.980: E/AndroidRuntime(599):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
  09-03 12:44:07.980: E/AndroidRuntime(599):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
  09-03 12:44:07.980: E/AndroidRuntime(599):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
  09-03 12:44:07.980: E/AndroidRuntime(599):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  09-03 12:44:07.980: E/AndroidRuntime(599):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
  09-03 12:44:07.980: E/AndroidRuntime(599):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
  09-03 12:44:07.980: E/AndroidRuntime(599):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
  09-03 12:44:07.980: E/AndroidRuntime(599):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
  09-03 12:44:07.980: E/AndroidRuntime(599): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.basicgl10test.MainActivity
  09-03 12:44:07.980: E/AndroidRuntime(599):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
  09-03 12:44:07.980: E/AndroidRuntime(599):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
  09-03 12:44:07.980: E/AndroidRuntime(599):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
  09-03 12:44:07.980: E/AndroidRuntime(599):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1023)
  09-03 12:44:07.980: E/AndroidRuntime(599):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1871)
  09-03 12:44:07.980: E/AndroidRuntime(599):    ... 11 more
  09-03 12:44:08.061: W/ActivityManager(92):   Force finishing activity com.example.basicgl10test/.MainActivity
```

My Activity Class is like this:

```
  package com.example.basicgl10test;
  import com.example.gl10gameadvlib.GL10GameActivity;
  import com.example.gl10gameadvlib.Screen;
  public class MainActivity extends GL10GameActivity {
```

The parent activity is like this in another package:

```
  package com.example.gl10gameadvlib;
  import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig;
  import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;
  public abstract class GL10GameActivity extends Activity {
```

There are no errors during build. I have recreated a fresh project, clean+build also, still the issue persists.

I am using Eclipse IDE with Android 4.0 Emulator. Issue stays with any emulator or real device.

Thanks
Souvik

Comment: Where did you put the jar containing `GL10GameActivity` class?

Comment: Have you configured your activity in the android manifest file?

Comment: Just try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11824038/940096)

Answer (score 63):

I faced this issue Right after **GOOGLE IO 2013** 
when i updated my **ADT plugin, Android SDK tools to Revision 22** 
and **Android SDK platform-tools to revision 17**

All of my projects that previously worked started throwing ClassNotFoundException after the update for no reason. 
Then i noticed that there is a new Android Package named as Android Private Libraries and after hours of trying i found a way to fix this.

Right Click on your Project then

Goto **Build Path-> Configure Build Path -> Order and Export**

when you are there you should check the **Android Private Libraries** and then click OK.

if you still face the problem delete all the files inside your bin folder and rebuilt you project.

Hope this solves your issue

Comment: Thanks a billion times! Me to had this exact same issue after the SDK upgrade after I/O 2013.

Comment: @Joram Teusink Glad to help

Comment: Thanks so much, just wasted 3 hours trying to figure out wtf is going on before stumbling across your post.

Comment: thank you so much. i spent half a day researching why all my apps stopped working.

Comment: Been struggling with this for hours ... Thx Sheraz

Comment: This worked for me also, but since I have 100+ Eclipse projects I found that the step **Build Path-> Configure Build Path -> Order and Export -> Android Private Libraries** is the same as replacing `<classpathentry kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.LIBRARIES"/>` with `<classpathentry exported="true" kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.LIBRARIES"/>` in the .classpath so I was able to search and replace this across all projects, then delete bin & gen folders and it worked!

Answer (score 3):

To make sure your jar is actually exported at build, you should either:

- put it in the `libs` folder
- or fill the checkbox corresponding to your jar in project properties > Java build path > Order and export tab

Answer (score 0):

If you are using some external libraries, except linking it inside Eclipse, don't forget to put them in "libs" folder in the application. It should be near /src, /res and etc. Just /libs/yourLibrary.jar.

It will tell the compiler(not exactly) to include this library to your APK.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the library I am importing is also an Android project and I have defined it as a library. In other projects, it is working the same way.

My manifest is as under:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.basicgl10test"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

    <!-- Only Single Touch and OpenGLES less than 2.0 versions used by default -->
    <!-- We will use both multi and single touch handlers by using a class based SDK Version qualifier -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue.
What I've done is:

1. Configure Build Path.
2. Choose Order and Export Tab,
3. Select all the listed path or JAR file.
4. And Try it!

Good Luck.