# Flashed 4.2.2 and now my Phonegap app won't run

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova

I re-installed the entire SDK along w/ Eclipse, but no dice. I am absolutely clueless as to how to debug this. I should note that it works fine on my partner's machine, but he uses a 4.1.2 ROM on his phone. Here is the error log: http://pastebin.com/yx2XT8qE

```
07-13 16:45:23.581: W/dalvikvm(12926): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/ahhaproductions/SMSapp/SMSapp; (42)
07-13 16:45:23.581: W/dalvikvm(12926): Link of class 'Lcom/ahhaproductions/SMSapp/SMSapp;' failed
07-13 16:45:23.581: D/AndroidRuntime(12926): Shutting down VM
07-13 16:45:23.581: W/dalvikvm(12926): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40b6b930)
07-13 16:45:23.591: I/Process(12926): Sending signal. PID: 12926 SIG: 9
07-13 16:45:23.591: E/AndroidRuntime(12926): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-13 16:45:23.591: E/AndroidRuntime(12926): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.ahhaproductions.SMSapp/com.ahhaproductions.SMSapp.SMSapp}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.ahhaproductions.SMSapp.SMSapp" on path: /mnt/asec/com.ahhaproductions.SMSapp-2/pkg.apk
07-13 16:45:23.591: E/AndroidRuntime(12926):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2224)
07-13 16:45:23.591: E/AndroidRuntime(12926):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358)
07-13 16:45:23.591: E/AndroidRuntime(12926):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:153)
07-13 16:45:23.591: E/AndroidRuntime(12926):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1247)
07-13 16:45:23.591: E/AndroidRuntime(12926):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-13 16:45:23.591: E/AndroidRuntime(12926):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-13 16:45:23.591: E/AndroidRuntime(12926):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5227)
07-13 16:45:23.591: E/AndroidRuntime(12926):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-13 16:45:23.591: E/AndroidRuntime(12926):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-13 16:45:23.591: E/AndroidRuntime(12926):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
07-13 16:45:23.591: E/AndroidRuntime(12926):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
07-13 16:45:23.591: E/AndroidRuntime(12926):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-13 16:45:23.591: E/AndroidRuntime(12926): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.ahhaproductions.SMSapp.SMSapp" on path: /mnt/asec/com.ahhaproductions.SMSapp-2/pkg.apk
07-13 16:45:23.591: E/AndroidRuntime(12926):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
07-13 16:45:23.591: E/AndroidRuntime(12926):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
07-13 16:45:23.591: E/AndroidRuntime(12926):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
07-13 16:45:23.591: E/AndroidRuntime(12926):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1054)
07-13 16:45:23.591: E/AndroidRuntime(12926):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2215)
07-13 16:45:23.591: E/AndroidRuntime(12926):    ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems insightful: [Android java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6443091/android-java-lang-runtimeexception-unable-to-instantiate-activity-componentinfo)

I decided to right-click the project > Build Path > Configure Build Path
And here I changed the order:

Original Order:

```
SMSApp/src,
SMSApp/gen,
Android 4.2.2,
Android Private Libraries,
Android Dependencies
```

Fixed Order:

```
Android Private Libraries,
SMSApp/src,
SMSApp/gen,
Android 4.2.2,
Android Dependencies
```

Make sure to check all the ones w/ dependencies (or all of them)

I then cleaned the project as usual and ran it and it worked.

EDIT: Apparently the ordering doesn't matter according to Dpa99c's comment below and the link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12243631/unable-to-resolve-superclass-of-activity?answertab=votes#tab-top).

Comment: The reordering is unnecessary; the important thing is to check the box for Android Private libraries - [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12243631/unable-to-resolve-superclass-of-activity?answertab=votes#tab-top)