# Class Not Found Exception on device, APP works on emulator

Tags: android, exception, android-viewpager

**EDIT:**
I have a solution for my problem, see below in the answers

I have searched and read all related questions on this issue, but none has worked for me.
I have an app which uses ViewPager Indicator as Library and it has a class application.

The app runs fine on the emulator, but when I try to export as signed apk.

Depending on the answers given for this exception and those which I have tried, it sometimes failed with error "Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1" or It exports correctly and crashes on the device.

Something peculiar though, when I run on the emulator, the apk generated is 600kb+ and when i export as signed apk it is around 300kb. It is somehow not referencing the library.

What I tried:

1. Default settings with only ViewPager referenced as library in the android properties
2. Adding JARs(ViewPager indicator and support ) in the libs folder

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11824038/940096) once with your app

Comment: Have you exported your jar files in Project> Properties > Java Build Path > Order and Export. Just go in there and check mark all your jar files.

Comment: fix your project properties from...Project > Android Tools > Fix Project Properties...and delete that project from eclipse then import it to eclipse...after that clean & build your project...

Comment: Yeh I did those. I noticed in the logs, it says "Cannot read jar file contents..." But the files are there in libs folder and referenced in build path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the issue was with proguard. If you have a class on the application level you should tell proguard to keep it public.

This is how I did it. I am currently using ADT20, I dont know if it is the same for older versions.

In file: **proguard-project.txt**
append this line (MyAPP being the class)

```
-keep public class <MyAPP>
```

In file: **project.properties**
uncomment this line

```
proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt
```

More info here:http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html#configuring