# No class defination found error even if there is no issues

Tags: android, eclipse

I am trying to clean, change the order of import/export in eclipse,check the package name like 100 times now still i m getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError...Its not working only for three classes and all others are working fine..what can be the issue..The three classes were not added recently but were from before and i just changed and renamed my package name...still my code works but the three classes(activities) are creating problem...the heirachy of the three are same with others they come in the same package..

I m stuck...plzzz help

Comment: check all jar files in libs folder and also the name is libs. if you are using any external jar files

Comment: Using any external jar files?

Comment: Make sure to check your layout xmls for any custom layout classes.  These won't present you with an error if the package name is wrong but will throw a NoClassDefFoundError if you try to inflate the xml.

Comment: Ohkk yess i m using external Jar...viewPager.jar..and yes i m using those in the three classes only...tell me where can i change???

Comment: @Spk tell me what to do if i have a jar file..android:support v4.jar    which i m using in the three classes..

Comment: Try removing the .jar then add it again.

Comment: [Just try this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11824038/940096)

Comment: @Spk thanks man it worked...thaks a lotttt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[just try this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11823975/getting-noclassdeffounderror-when-using-common-lang-stringutils-in-android-java/11824038#11824038)

This worked  for me..Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this because of your .jar file didn't import properly. Follow below steps -

1. Place your `.jar` file in your project's `libs` folder.
2. Import it into your project. And, `GoTo project -> properties -> Java build path -> order tab.`
3. Check, whether your .jar file checked and placed in order of 1st. This is the main thing.

Hope these steps helps you. Have a look at below image -

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you had put your jar files in lib folder change its name to libs. Then build path from that libs folder.