# Android Twitter4j giving error NoClassDefFoundError: twitter4j.http.AccessToken

Tags: android

I downloaded twitter sample application in `AndroidTwitterSample` repository and imported my eclipse. I am trying to run that sample application and i got the error: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` in logcat.

Comment: Are you using any external jar files? Simply try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11824038)

Comment: I think your library is not correctly configured with your project..

Comment: Setting Up a Project to Use a Library: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12619865/1012284

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see my post-  [No class defination found error even if there is no issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12708744/no-class-defination-found-error-even-if-there-is-no-issues/12710111#12710111)  & let me know if this not working in your side.

Answer (score 1):

The error is based on jar file missing.you must place jar files rite place.

Create a folder named libs inside the root directory of your project and put twitter4j jar inside.

Then include new jar via Project **Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries -> Add Jars.**

Remove any old reference to twitter4j jars.

Clean and launch.

I hope this will helpful to you.

Comment: in my project already lib folder is available and also inside twitter jar file avaiable

Comment: @user1717339 Have you tried out my answer in your question's comment.

Comment: @user1717339 yes already you are used lib folder.but that lib folder is not associated to your project or path mismatching.Then only you got this error.https://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html#SettingUp,and http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/10/changes-to-library-projects-in-android.html.Refer this link for the library folder handled in Android app.